# Rails bundle error when pushing to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had an app deployed on Heroku and I am currently trying to create the same app on AWS.
I've copied my folder, created a complete separated repo on Github and installed ebcli, the setup looks fine.

When I try to run eb deploy, I have this error:
 [Instance: i-03051e2a022886184] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in`activate_bin_path'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `'.

I've looked online and it says it comes from incompatibility between your gemlock file bundler version and actual bundler version.

I've tried to change my bundler version to this one, but I gave up and came back to 2.0.1 because I had to install too many dependencies otherwise.
I removed the gemlock, bundle again, but I still got the same error when trying to deploy.

With my heroku version, it always worked.

Any idea how to solve that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: do you have bundler gem in Gemfile ?

Comment: hi! Actally I don't. Just did gem install bundler on my terminal. Do I need to add it in the gemfile as well?

Comment: You shouldn't need to mess with the bundler on EB. Did you look at the last 100 lines of logs for the `/var/log/eb-activity.log` file?  Are there any other errors further up?

Answer (score 2):

We moved from Heroku to AWS a few months back as well and it will likely take some some custom scripting to get things to work.

It would help to know more about your EB environment, but I am assuming you are using Ruby 2.5 with Puma on Amazon Linux 2.9.0 (?)

Not sure what bundle version comes with that, But I don’t think it’s 2.x. so you have to add an .ebextensions file too install your preferred bundled version.

```
# .ebextensions/01_install_bundler.config

container_commands:
  install_bundler:
    command: “gem install bundler —-version 2.0.0”
```

More info on [AWS Linux customizations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands)

End of the day, we are much happier with our AWS environment (lower cost, better performance), but requires more work to get it set up

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes, Ruby 2.5.3 with Puma.  I've added the extensions folder and the file you mentionned, but still not working... I  get the same error

Comment: I do not have the answer yet, but I do know that running by ssh `gem install bundler` updates bundler to the latest version. Running afterwards `bundler -v` still shows the old version. `export BUNDLER_VERSION=2.0.1` then `bundler -v` display the correct version. Hopefully it will help you figure out the right fix

Answer (score -1):

Actually the problem exists because the bundler version in the eb env is older than the one being used in the project source.

So the solution is to use a bundler version less or equal the eb env installed version.

First uninstalled the current bundler:

> gem uninstall bundle

and then install the desired one:

> gem install bundler -v 1.16.6

[See more details](http://apgortsilas.aggate.gr/elms/aws-eb-deploy-cant-find-gem-bundler-issue)